# Computing PageRank Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, page-rank

I have been given the adjacency matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0&1&1 \\ 1 & 0 &1&1& 0\\ 0& 1 &0&0&1 \\1&1&0&0&1 \\0&1&1&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$ 
And I have been asked to find the H-matrix and the page rank vector

I found the H-matrix to be
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/3 & 0&1/3&1/3 \\ 1/3 & 0 &1/3&1/3& 0\\ 0& 1/2 &0&0&1/2 \\1/3&1/3&0&0&1/3 \\0&1/2&1/2&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that to the page rank vector is found from $r_{n} = r_{0}H^n$ where $$r_{0} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\end{pmatrix}$$ in this case

So to get $r_{n}$, I need to find $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} H^{n} $ then the page rank vector is $$ r_{n} = r_{0}L$$

I am not sure how to calculate this limit in order to find the page rank vector
What is the best way to find the limit for the matrix H ?i.e $\lim_{n \to \infty} H^{n}$

Comment: Note that $H$ is a row-stochastic matrix (the rows have nonnegative entries which sum to $1$), so each row of $\lim_{n\to\infty} H^n$ is given by $\pi$ where $\pi$ is a left-eigenvector for $H$, i.e. $\pi = \pi H$. You can find $\pi$ by solving the equations $\pi(I-H)=0$ and $\sum_i \pi_i=1$.

Comment: so i should get $\pi_1 = \frac{\pi_2}{3} + \frac{\pi_4}{3}+ \frac{\pi_5}{3}$ for the first row and so on and the just solve the system of equations?

Comment: The equations are by column, since we're using left-multiplication here.

Comment: so $\pi_1 = \frac{\pi_2}{3} + \frac{\pi_4}{3}$ for the first and then solve using the rest?

Comment: Yes. Note that the equations $\pi(I-H)=0$ are linearly dependent, so you will only need to use four of them (along with the equation $\sum_i \pi_i = 1$).